# How to add serial number for each group in Spark DataFrame

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I am trying to add a column to my Spark DataFrame with a serial number based on a condition: I would like to assign sequential integers for each group in one of the columns.

I have tried many approaches,but nothing seems to be working.

```
df<-data.frame(location=c("a","a","d","d","d"),
               device_id=c(123,3455,234,4565,675),
               expected_column=c(1,2,1,2,3))

#final_data_visitor is my spark Data Frame 
random_data<-final_data_visitor

random_data<-random_data %>%
       group_by(location_id,device_subscriber_id)%>%                
       mutate(visit_seq=1:n())

random_data
# error is "Error in from:to : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:n() : NAs introduced by coercion"
```

This is the error I get when I try to execute my code:

> "Error in from:to : NA/NaN argument
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In 1:n() : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` window function, but to be able to apply it, you'll need some form of ordering.  For example, if data is defined as below

```
set.seed(1)
df <- copy_to(sc, tibble(group=rep(c("a", "b"), 3), value=runif(6)))
```

you can

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(value, .by_group=TRUE) %>%  
  mutate(r = row_number())
```

```
# Source:     lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database:   spark_connection
# Groups:     group
# Ordered by: value, TRUE
  group value     r
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 b     0.372     1
2 b     0.898     2
3 b     0.908     3
4 a     0.202     1
5 a     0.266     2
6 a     0.573     3
```

In case of no predefined ordering you could try add one using `montonically_increasing_id` (please make sure you understand Spark's ordering semantics first) or, if you don't care about the order the same column you use for grouping:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(group, .by_group=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(r = row_number())
```

```
# Source:     lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database:   spark_connection
# Groups:     group
# Ordered by: group, TRUE
  group value     r
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 a     0.266     1
2 a     0.573     2
3 a     0.202     3
4 b     0.372     1
5 b     0.908     2
6 b     0.898     3
```

If applied this way, order of values in a group will be nondeterministic.

Comment: I am getting an error "Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`value`' given input columns:"

Comment: @YogeshKumar Obviously column names should reflect your actual data. The answer contains minimal reproducible dataset, to run it on your own input, you'll have to adjust it accordingly.